# CSS not working in some pages on Django

Tags: python, css, django, reference

I am a beginner in Python and Django and I have been struggling with the following problem:

On localhost:8000/ webiste is beautiful and working fine but on localhost:8000/invoice/ SOME references are not working. CSS for example does not work but images and JavaScript do.

I am using relative links to point out where my path is.

```
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/skel.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/skel-layers.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/init.js" %}"></script>

    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/skel.css" %}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/style-xlarge.css" %}"/>
    </noscript>

    <img src="{% static "images/pic07.jpg" %}" alt="" />
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
)
```

View.py

```
def home(request):
  return render(request, 'principal.html',)

def invoice(request):
  return render(request, 'invoice.html',)
```

When I check the page code with the browser I see the links are being referred as http://localhost:8000/invoice/static/css/somecss.css.

invoice.html is inside /project/folder/templates/ and my .css is inside /project/static/css/. invoice.html is inside the same folder my index.html (principal.html) page, which is working is.

Also, all links inside website/invoice/ page become website/invoice/link instead of website/link

Comment: What CSS? Your example doesn't actually show any... Please give a [mcve]

Comment: In fact, you are using django framework, not just "python". where is invoice.html?

Comment: invoice.html is inside project/folder/templates/ and my .css is inside /project/static/css/. invoice.html is inside the same folder my index.html page, which is working is.

Comment: I have removed <noscript> tag and it worked. However, I dont know why it worked on my index and it did not on invoice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved removing  tag. Also for 404 errors on console due to js files referencing other css files, I added a variable to my template to include the url:

```
<script>
  var url = "{% static 'css/' %}";
</script>
```

And inside .js I used url.concat('style.css')